# FFMPEG on PHP could not open file

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, exec

Currently, I'm running the latest FFMPEG (4.2.1) on MacOS Catalina.
I'm trying to join multiple image to become an mp4 video using FFMPEG executed with PHP exec()

here is my ffmpeg code

```
"/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -filter_complex \"[0]reverse[r];[0][r]concat, loop=1:50, setpts=N/12/TB\" -r 25 -f image2 -i /Users/Dan/Desktop/RAW/0234_%02d.jpg -preset fast -crf 23 -profile:v baseline -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/render/result/result.mp4 2>&1"
```

Here is the output of FFMPEG

```
 Array (
     [0] => ffmpeg version 4.2.1-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
     [1] =>   built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
     [2] =>   configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
     [3] =>   libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
     [4] =>   libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
     [5] =>   libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
     [6] =>   libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
     [7] =>   libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
     [8] =>   libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
     [9] =>   libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
     [10] =>   libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
     [11] => [image2 @ 0x7fe4b1000400] Could not open file : /Users/Dan/Desktop/RAW/0234_01.jpg
     [12] => [image2 @ 0x7fe4b1000400] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown)):
 unspecified size
     [13] => Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
     [14] => Input #0, image2, from '/Users/Dan/Desktop/RAW/0234_%02d.jpg':
     [15] =>   Duration: 00:00:00.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
     [16] =>     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, none(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
     [17] => Stream mapping:
     [18] =>   Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> reverse
     [19] =>   Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> concat:in0:v0
     [20] =>   setpts -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
     [21] => Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
     [22] => [image2 @ 0x7fe4b1000400] Could not open file : /Users/Dan/Desktop/RAW/0234_01.jpg
     [23] => /Users/Dan/Desktop/RAW/0234_%02d.jpg: Input/output error
     [24] => Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
     [25] => Error marking filters as finished
     [26] => Conversion failed!
 )
```

On the 11th row, ffmpeg could not open the file, although the file permission already read and write for everyone.
Is it something I missed for the ffmpeg code?

Note: The ffmpeg code above can be run on terminal successfully

Comment: See also: [How to check if a user can access a given file?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/82347)

Comment: @mario every folder path to the file already set to read and write for everyone

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same exact issue with `Could not open file : [filename]`. The user has is the owner of the directory and everything should work. My solution was to create an empty file and then be sure to use the `-y` flag to say yes to any prompt (i.e. `ffmpeg -y [rest of command]`).

It definitely still seems permissions related. Maybe something to do with how PHP's `exec()` works. But this definitely was the solution for me. Hopefully someone finds this helpful after 1 year and 7 months with no other replies :-)